# How to make a responsive div stick to page edge

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my responsive image gallery div to "stick" to the right edge of the browser window with no space between (see image example below).

Current site: http://parkerrichard.com/studiogreen/html/project-01.html

It worked previously when I added

```
container {
width: 100%;
}
```

But now that doesn't effect the gallery div (flexslider). I've tried adding the following to the "flexslider" css properties to no avail:

```
flexslider {
position: absolute; 
float: right; 
right: 0px; 
width 100%;
}
```

None of it seems to create the desired effect. Any advice or help would be appreciated.

Example of how I want page to appear:
[image: Image runs to right edge of screen]

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=“UTF-8”>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Studio Green</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Typekit custom fonts -->
    <script src="//use.typekit.net/bcn3ife.js"></script>
    <script>try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>

    <link href="css/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>

    <!-- custom icons -->
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="fonts/flexslider-icon.eot">

</head>

<body>
    <!-- row 1: static navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png"></a>
        </div><!-- navbar toggle -->
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="process.html">PROCESS</a></li>
            <li><a href="office.html">OFFICE</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/nav-collapse -->
      </div><!-- container -->
    </nav><!-- navbar -->

    <!-- row 2: body -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row centered">

            <!-- sidebar -->
                <aside class="navbar-collapse collapse panel-group col-lg-3 col-med-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                          RESIDENTIAL
                    </li>
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="drop"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down nav-caret"></span></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="project-01.html">PROJECT <span class="spaced">1</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="project-01.html">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">2</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="project-01.html">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">3</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="project-01.html">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">4</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="project-01.html">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">5</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="project-01.html">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">6</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="project-01.html">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">7</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="project-01.html">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">8</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="project-01.html">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">9</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="project-01.html">PROJECT  <span class="spaced">10</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a href="schools.html">
                      SCHOOLS
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a href="parks.html">
                      PARKS
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a href="hospitality.html">
                      HOSPITALITY
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
              </div>              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFive">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFive">
                      ELEMENTS
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFive">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="drop"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down nav-caret"></span></li>
                        <li><a href="plants.html">ENTRY</a></li>
                        <li><a href="plants.html">FENCES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="plants.html">FIRE</a></li>
                        <li><a href="plants.html">LIGHTING</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="plants.html">PAVING</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="plants.html">PLANTS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="plants.html">POOLS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="plants.html">SEATING</a></li>
                        <li><a href="plants.html">SCULPTURE</a></li>
                        <li><a href="plants.html">STAIRS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="plants.html">SUSTAINABILITY</a></li>
                        <li><a href="plants.html">WATER</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </aside>

            <!-- slideshow gallery -->          
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-7 pull-left">
                <div class="flexslider">
                  <ul class="slides">
                    <li>
                      <img src="img/project-1_01.jpg" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img src="img/project-1_02.jpg" />
                      <p class="flex-caption right"><span class="strong">PROJECT <span class="sm-spaced">1</span></span><br />
                            Location: Los Altos Hills, CA<br />
                            Architect: SDG Architects<br />
                            Grass, along with large specimen and Redwoods comprise the restorative Restraint, minimalization, and restoration landscape allows this home to exude quiet, restraint, minimalization, and restoration landscape.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img src="img/project-1_03.jpg" />
                      <p class="flex-caption right"><span class="strong">PROJECT <span class="sm-spaced">1</span></span><br />
                          Location: Los Altos Hills, CA<br />
                          Architect: SDG Architects<br />
                          Exude quiet, California Fescue, Berkeley Sedge, Coyote Needle Grass, along with large specimen and Redwoods.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img src="img/project-1_04.jpg" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img src="img/project-1_05.jpg" />
                      <p class="flex-caption right"><span class="strong">PROJECT <span class="sm-spaced">1</span></span><br />
                            Location: Los Altos Hills, CA<br />
                            Architect: SDG Architects<br />
                            Coyote Needle Grass, along with large specimen and Redwoods comprise the restorative allows this home to exude quiet, Restraint, minimalization, and restoration landscape allows this home to exude quiet, California Fescue, Berkeley Sedge, Coyote Needle Grass, along.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img src="img/project-1_06.jpg" />
                      <p class="flex-caption right"><span class="strong">PROJECT <span class="sm-spaced">1</span></span><br />
                            Location: Los Altos Hills, CA<br />
                            Architect: SDG Architects<br />
                            Large specimen and Redwoods comprise the restorative Restraint, minimalization, and restoration landscape allows this home to exude quiet, Restraint, minimalization, and restoration landscape allows this home to exude quiet, California Fescue, Berkeley Sedge, Coyote Needle Grass.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img src="img/project-1_07.jpg" />
                      <p class="flex-caption right"><span class="strong">PROJECT <span class="sm-spaced">1</span></span><br />
                            Location: Los Altos Hills, CA<br />
                            Architect: SDG Architects<br />
                            Fescue, Berkeley Sedge, Coyote Needle Grass, along with large specimen and Redwoods comprise the restorative Restraint, minimalization, and restoration landscape allows this home to exude quiet, Restraint, minimalization.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img src="img/project-1_08.jpg" />
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- address -->
            <address>232 SIR FRANCIS DRAKE BLVD</br>
            SAN ANSELMO, CA 94960</br>
            415 721 0905</address>
        </div><!--/row -->
    </div><!--/container -->


    <!-- javaspcript -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(window).load(function() {
          $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "fade"
          });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/* this is a custom css stylesheet */


/* ==========================================================================
   Base Styles, Bootstrap Modifications & Fonts Import
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * A better looking default horizontal rule
 */

hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.centered {
    text-align: center;
}

.img-centered {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.mt-lg {
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.mt {
    margin-top: 80px;
}

.mb {
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.drop {
    margin-bottom: -15px;
}

.spaced {
    margin-left: 37px;
}

.sm-spaced {
    margin-left: 5px;
}


/* ==========================================================================
   General styles
   ========================================================================== */

html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
    font-family: "proxima-nova", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #555;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
}

a {
    color: #555;
    outline: 0;
}

.strong {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
}

small {
    color: #555;
}

aside {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

address {
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 23px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    float: right;
    padding: 90px 0px 30px 15px;
    margin-right: 70px;
}

.email {
    color: #6CAA3D;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.info-box {
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 17px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    width: 315px;
    height: 450px;
    padding: 60px 20px 0 15px;
}

.info-box p {
    padding-top: 12px;
}

.info-box h5 {
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.contact {
    height: auto!important;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 315px;
}

.team-box img {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Navigation styles
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * Top nav section
 */

.navbar-header {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 0px!important;
}

.navbar .nav {
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 45px;
}

.navbar .nav > li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #555;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .active > a, a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
    color: #6CAA3D;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
    padding: 0px 15px 15px 15px;
}

.navbar-collapse {
    margin-top: -65px;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-color: none;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.logo {
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}

.navbar-right {
    padding: 15px 20px 0 0;
}

/*
 * Left aside nav
 */

.panel {
    border: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.0);
    box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.0);
    margin: 45px 0 0 100px;
}

.panel-title {
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #555;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    list-style: none;
}

.panel-title a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.panel-default > .panel-heading {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
}

.panel-body {
    margin-left: -25px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.panel-body ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.panel-body ul li {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.panel-group {
    text-align: left;
}

.panel-group .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .panel-body {
    border-top:0px;
}

.nav-caret {
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 8px;
}

/*
 * flexslider format
 */

.flexslider{
    background:none !important;
    border:none !important;
    box-shadow:none !important;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
}

.flex-direction-nav a  {
    color: #999 !important;
}

/*.flex-next { 
    padding-right: 40px!important;
}*/

.flex-control-nav {
    text-align: right !important;
    padding-right: 70px !important;
}

.flex-control-paging li a {
    color: transparent !important;
}

.nodot .flex-control-paging li a { 
    display: none !important;
}

.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active {
    background: #6CAA3D !important;
}

.right {
    padding-top: auto !important;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.flex-caption {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 11px;
    width: 300px;
}

.flex-caption p {
    padding-top: 12px;
}

.carousel .slides > li {
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for one you should be floating the parent of `.flexslider` to the right instead of the left.

```
<div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-sm-7 pull-left">
```

You have a class called `.pull-left` added to that so im assuming you can change that to `.pull-right`. Then you need to remove `padding-right: 15px` from `.container` and it should sit against the right side

Comment: sry this comment is off topic to your answer but i was checking out your profile and stumbled into the the nycdevshop site. Can you please tell me the name of the effect the main page has, where the stars and planets move as if moving away from center. Sorry I couldnt message you any other way

Comment: yeah no problem, it's called `parallax` and is pretty common. If you google it you will see alot of different types of parallax. That was a custom script I wrote for the site.

Comment: Thanks that page looks awesome. Now i have to figure out how to do it lol

Comment: haha thanks. There are tons of tutorials and examples online, you can be creative with it once you get the hang of it